# Show that $p$ is a stationary solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be open and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ a continuous vector field. Show that if for some $p\in\Omega$ there is a solution $\gamma:]a,\infty[\to\mathbb \Omega$ of $x'=f(x)$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\gamma(t)= p$, then $p$ is a stationary solution.

I had one idea but I doubt that it works like this: If $\lim_{t\to\infty} \gamma(t)=p$ and $\gamma$ is continuous, can I conclude $\lim_{t\to\infty}\gamma'(t)=0$?

If that were the case the fact that $f$ is continuous would further yield $$f(p)=f(\lim_{t\to\infty}\gamma(t))=\lim_{t\to\infty}f(\gamma(t))=\lim _{t\to\infty}\gamma'(t)=0$$ making $p$ a continuous solution. If my approach is wrong though and can't be fixed, how do I prove this result?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f(p)=v\ne 0$, then $|f(x)-v|\le\frac12|v|$ for $x\in B(p,\delta)$ for some $δ>0$. Now per the limit assumption, $|γ(t)-p|<δ$ for $t>T$ where $T$ depends on $δ$. Then also
$$
γ(t)-γ(T)-v\,(t-T)=\int_T^t(f(γ(s)-v)\,ds
$$
so that
$$
|γ(t)-γ(T)-v\,(t-T)|\le \frac12|v|\,(t-T)
$$
which is impossible to satisfy for all $t>T$, as
$$
|γ(t)-γ(T)-v\,(t-T)|\ge |v|\,(t-T)-2δ
$$
grows faster than the bound.

Comment: @user539887 : You were right, I changed to a more direct solution approach.

Comment: I just upvoted your answer.  I will delete my comment of yesterday, as it is no longer valid.